# Div align middle inside in rotated div

Tags: html, css

I've made the following JSfiddle to see my actual problem. I want a rotated div to be full width.

I already achieved that by giving it `120%` width and make `overflow:hidden` in the container (I wanted the rotated div not to have empty spaces in corners).

Now I want to place something in the middle. I tried with margin:0 auto but because its `120%` it goes to the right center. I want to be exactly in the middle of the screen (and on different screens of course)

Here is the code and [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qf2tg/1/):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="rotaded">
        <p>
            <img src="http://imgcdn.nrelate.com/image_cache/www.valcun.com/fc95c92475a927c2bc5130b343e2c5f8_thumb_short-url.png">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
.rotaded {
    background:red;
    width:120%;
    height:200px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
}
p {
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

Comment: if it is  only text or image to be centered, then add a border-right to grow your box, remove width on <p> and set text-align:center : http://jsfiddle.net/qf2tg/6/ ... like i answered below :)

Comment: if your 2 boxes are set as inline-boxes, they will take text-align, can you provide a jsfiddle closer to your reality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your math (and everything else) will be easier if you use the alternate to rotate, skew:

```
.container {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
.rotaded {
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
}
p {
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

The **Main** advantage is that skewY won't change the width of the transformed element (and the vertical sides go on being vertical), that seems to be what you want

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/qf2tg/9/)

Comment: yeah i chatted with @Hashem Qolami and he proposed that too! and it worked! Thank you too!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your 120% width... then it seems as though 20% is going to the right off screen..

So instead of that, lets have 10% go off to the right, and 10% off to the left, so its even.

So try

```
.rotaded {
    margin-left: -10%;
}
```

or

```
.rotaded {
    left: -10%;
    position: relative; //likely need to add this
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work :/ try resizing the jsfiddle window. It's not in the middle

Comment: This was my initial thought too, but the rotation messes it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding this line:

```
/*margin: 0 0 0 30%;*/   

.container {
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;

}
.rotaded {
    background:red;
    width:120%;
    height:200px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
}
p {
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
    margin: 0 0 0 30%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you had a transparent border of anysize on the right, it will show your background all the way through, even if it is a background-image:
http://jsfiddle.net/qf2tg/5/

```
.container {
            overflow:hidden;
            width:100%;
        }
        .rotaded {
            background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/800/nature);/* let use an image instead color  
    to see what it does ;) */
            width:100%;
            border-right:100px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);/* here grow your container 
    to have it overflow 
    , beware of the use of box-sizing :) 
    and give enough width to your border, 
    higher is the container, bigger is the gap to fill  */
            height:200px;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
            -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
            -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
        }
        p {
            text-align:center;
            height:200px;
            position:relative;
            top:20px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
            -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
            -moz-transform-origin: top left;
        }
```

to center your image, do not give a `width` to `<p>`, but a `text-align:center;` should do fine .

higher will be height or rotation will be, bigger will be the gap to fill,you need to  increase border's width as much as needed to fill it.

Comment: increase your border width as much as needed ,so it fills enough space

Comment: It doesn't fill any space :P It's just moving the div inside the white rotated box to the left :'(

Comment: Here is a screenshot.. http://i.imgur.com/klshY5P.png The yellow is the border.. it goes to the right when i grow the pixels

Comment: okay, i can see that border is not big enough to fill all space, have you try to set a hudge value like 1000px to the right transparent border ?  here a codepen with 2 p side by side  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vzIpy (direction/dir of document is ltr , the opposite would need a left border )

Comment: I just uploaded my project http://hambos22.me/test_aniva/Aniva/ You can check there what i mean

Comment: your * { box-sizing: border-box; } messes it up , it includes border into width, reset it for your panel to content-box for instance , like here http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vzIpy (updated pen with -moz-box-sizing)